# How to keep a value unchanged?

Tags: jquery

This is probably a basic question, but...

```
<div id="caption">323</div>

var a = $("#caption").html();
```

Now, the content of `#caption` is changed...

And I need the starting value (323)

```
alert (a);
```

But the result is the new value.

How can I keep the starting value unchanged ?

Comment: Store it in some variable on document.ready ?

Comment: Explain what exactly you are doing after page load it's updating or on any click

Comment: This... makes... no... sense... at... all...

Comment: @YogeshSharma, `323` is changed to `525`, for example, by clicking on a button

Comment: Ok so best method is store caption div value in a variable on page load and then use that variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var old=$('#caption').html();
$('#sub').on('click',function(){
    $('#caption').html('525');
    alert(old);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/M4Em8/)